# CCNet triggers build, but succeeds even if I check in bad code to svn

Tags: .net, svn, nant, ccnet-config

I have set up CruiseControl for .NET with SVN as my source control and using NAnt build script. When I manually build the visual studio solution I get errors, which is correct because I have some bad code. After I checked in the code to svn, CCNet triggered the build, but the result shows as SUCCESS. Please see the config and build files below:

**NAnt build file:**

```
<project name="MyServiceClient" default="build">
  <target name="init" depends="clean" />
  <target name="clean" />
  <target name="checkout"/>
  <target name="compile"/>
  <!--<target name="deploy"/>
  <target name="test"/>
  <target name="inspect"/>-->
  <target name="build" depends="init, checkout">
    <call target="compile" />
<!--    <call target="inspect" />
    <call target="test" />
    <call target="deploy" />-->
  </target>
</project>
```

### **ccnet.config**

```
<cruisecontrol>

  <project name="MyServiceClient">
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>https://dev-wks28.dev.va.root:8443/svn/test/trunk/MyServiceClient</trunkUrl>
  <executable>C:/Program Files/VisualSVN Server/bin/svn.exe</executable>
  <workingDirectory>C:\test\MyServiceClient</workingDirectory>
  <username>kpedda</username>
  <password>Password1</password>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
</sourcecontrol>
<workingDirectory>C:\test\MyServiceClient</workingDirectory>
<triggers>
  <intervalTrigger seconds="90" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" />
  <scheduleTrigger time="10:00" buildCondition="ForceBuild" />
</triggers>
<tasks>
  <nant>
    <executable>C:/Program Files/NAnt/bin/nant.exe</executable>
    <baseDirectory>C:/Apps</baseDirectory>
    <!--<workingDirectory>C:/test/MyServiceClient</workingDirectory>-->
    <!--<projectFile>MyServiceClient.sln</projectFile>-->
    <buildFile>default.build</buildFile>
    <targetList>
      <target>build</target>
    </targetList>
  </nant>
</tasks>
<publishers>
  <xmllogger/>
</publishers>
```

Can anybody please tell me what's going on?

Comment: what does default.build look like?

Comment: If you paste in the NAnt build file, it may help out.

Comment: Here is the build file

**NAnt build file:**

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MyServiceClient" default="build">
  <target name="init" depends="clean" />
  <target name="clean" />
  <target name="checkout"/>
  <target name="compile"/>
  <!--<target name="deploy"/>
  <target name="test"/>
  <target name="inspect"/>-->
  <target name="build" depends="init, checkout">
    <call target="compile" />
<!--    <call target="inspect" />
    <call target="test" />
    <call target="deploy" />-->
  </target>
</project>

Comment: Can you confirm that you have checked in the bad code and not some other files?  If the erroneous code has not been committed then this is the expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, i have committed the changes through the tortoise shell. i tried couple of times by changing and commiting

Comment: Have you tried calling nant build from the command line on your local machine - does it pass or fail?

Comment: i tried executing the command line nant. it also succeeds. but the code in the source control should not and does not build in Visual studio.
OK i got one doubt just now,May i know what the workingDirectory tag in the config file mean? Is it the place where the code is checked out and modified. If it is right, then i am in the right path but unable o get it work.

Answer (score 1):

Your NANT pasted again:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="MyServiceClient" default="build">
    <target name="init" depends="clean" /> <target name="clean" />
    <target name="checkout"/>
    <target name="compile"/>
    <!--<target name="deploy"/> <target name="test"/> <target name="inspect"/>-->
    <target name="build" depends="init, checkout">
         <call target="compile" />
         <!-- <call target="inspect" /> <call target="test" /> <call target="deploy" />-->
    </target>
</project>
```

This script does nothing. NANT does not even look at your sourcecode with this script.

Comment: Evan, can you please correct me what i am doing wrong in this NAnt script?

Comment: It's just that the compile directive is empty. I can only assume that you did not remove the body of the directive due to your inclusion of other commented out directives.